# MN 122: Was the Buddha unsociable?

Tags: metta

MN 122 says:

> Ananda, there is this abiding discovered by the Tathagata: to enter
> and abide in voidness internally by giving no attention to all signs.
> If, while the Tathagata is abiding thus, he is visited by bhikkhus or
> bhikkhunis, by men or women lay followers, by kings or kings'
> ministers, by other sectarians or their disciples, then with a mind
> leaning to seclusion, tending and inclining to seclusion, withdrawn,
> delighting in renunciation, and altogether done with things that are
> the basis for taints, he invariably talks to them **in a way concerned
> with dismissing them.**

Was the Buddha unsociable? If not, what is the meaning of the above verse?

Answer (score 2):

Ven. Sujato translates it,

> In that case, with a mind slanting, sloping, and inclining to seclusion, withdrawn, and loving renunciation, he invariably gives each of them a talk emphasizing the topic of dismissal.

Again, "dismissal" is the topic, the doctrine: which (the doctrine in general and, in context, this passage of this sutta in particular) is to do with dismissing "sights" and so on, dismissing *infatuation*...

That's what the "them" is in your quote -- I think it's not about dismissing *people*, being harsh to students.

Though it is about not "relishing" company, becoming infatuated with the pleasures of company, and engaging in "low" speech.

Comment: Interesting, the dictionary says: uyyojanikapaṭisaṁyutta - connected with rousing action; coupled with a dismissal https://suttacentral.net/define/uyyojanikapa%E1%B9%ADisa%E1%B9%81yutta

Answer (score 2):

> Was the Buddha unsociable? If not, what is the meaning of the above verse?

Ven. Bodhi's note citing the Commentary's explanation:

> MA: The Buddha begins the present passage in order to ward off the criticism that while he enjoins his disciples to live in solitude, he himself is often surrounded by a large retinue.

Answer (score 1):

As good householder wouldn't listen, nor understand, the Arahats could not do more then to dismiss him with with metta "may he conduct in ways that he may find the path to peace for himself with ease." Metta gives others all freedom and prevents one to get touched by what's bond. So now again free to act more wise, or further unwise, if wishing so.

Those who could receive the Dhamma, are dismissed as well. Who would miss liberated, if liberated by oneself?

Comment: i marked this answer down because for me it clearly contains false unsubstantiated speech or slander, what the Bible calls "false testimony".